# How to change body background when clicking on li element

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click on the "Sign Out" anchor, I want the body of my design.html document to turn black and for a pop up blurb, like a speech bubble, to pop up next to where the word sign out originally was. Having this effect means you shouldn't be able to see "Sign Out" because the color of that list element is also black.

I'm working on the first part--getting hovering over a list element to change the color of the body of the document.

The JavaScript I've posted does nothing to my web page. No changes when we mouse over or mouse out.

What changes should I make to get the desired effect?

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("li").addEventListener("mouseover", function ()
  document.body.style.background = black
);

document.getElementsByTagName("li").addEventListener("mouseout", function ()
  document.body.style.background = pink
);
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  margin: 50px;
}

#leftlist {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  bottom: 40%;
}

#rightlist {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 40%;
}

#bottomlist {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25%;
  bottom: 10%;
}

#bottomlist li {
  display: inline;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3 id="header">Design Mode</h3>
  
  <ul id="leftlist">
    <li>View </li>
    <li>Coping Skills</li>
    <li>Notes to Self</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="rightlist">
    <li>Objects</li>
    <li>Background</li>
    <li>Sound</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="bottomlist">
    <li><a href="../homepage/index.html">Sign Out</a></li>
    <li width=10px>Sign in Using Different Username</li>
    <li>Save</li>
  </ul>

  <!-- script type="text/javascript" src="scriptdesign.js" defer -->
</body>
```

Comment: Also, any comments on better programming practices are much appreciated.

Comment: You have an error in your js function() { }. You forgot the brackets

Comment: _Braces_, but yeah. See the console error.

Comment: Also, `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of elements. If you want to add event listeners to each one, you will need to loop through them.

Comment: You also need to put quotes around `"black"` and `"pink"`, see W3Schools background on how to use this properly https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_background.asp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `querySelectorAll()` to get a collection of elements which you can then iterate over with `forEach` to add the event handlers.

Also, you need to put quotes around the colours you want to use.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    document.body.style.background = "black"
  })
});

document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    document.body.style.background = "pink"
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  margin: 50px;
}

#leftlist {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  bottom: 40%;
}

#rightlist {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 40%;
}

#bottomlist {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25%;
  bottom: 10%;
}

#bottomlist li {
  display: inline;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3 id="header">Design Mode</h3>

  <ul id="leftlist">
    <li>View </li>
    <li>Coping Skills</li>
    <li>Notes to Self</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="rightlist">
    <li>Objects</li>
    <li>Background</li>
    <li>Sound</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="bottomlist">
    <li><a href="../homepage/index.html">Sign Out</a></li>
    <li width=10px>Sign in Using Different Username</li>
    <li>Save</li>
  </ul>

  <!-- script type="text/javascript" src="scriptdesign.js" defer -->
</body>
```